# PHP Вывести значение переменной масcива по id другого

Tags: php, массивы, foreach, while

Всем привет. У меня есть массив, который используется для поля select

```
 $data_areas = array ( 
    [0] => Терапевтическая стоматология 
    [1] => Хирургическая стоматология 
    [2] => Ортопедическая стоматология 
    [3] => Эстетическая стоматология 
    [4] => Детская стоматология )
```

При выборе пункта, возвращает только переменную, содержащую число, без значения. Мне же нужно вывести значение, зная это число, например 4

Сразу скажу, что простые условия, такого вида не подходят, т.к. основной массив динамический и будет изменяться

```
if( $tag == '4' )
$text = 'Детская стоматология';
echo "<p>$text</p>";
```

Подскажите, как решить задачу)

Comment: `echo $data_areas[$tag];`?

Comment: Ох, точно! 4 часа уже мучаюсь, перебирая вариации циклов while, чтобы сравнить значения)) Спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы о выводе значения по индексу/ключу, то `echo $data_areas[$tag];`.